# Family Safety App Locker error 454

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, crash

I have created aMicrosoft Family with a few other members. I am the Family organiser, they are  adult members of my family (not kids). Thus they all have their own Microsoft account.

I bought “Age Of Empires 2: Definitive Edition” on Windows 10 and shared it with them thanks to Microsoft Store family sharing system.

However when we play together on an online match, some of us randomly crash to desktop with no error message. Using `Event Viewer` we managed to find the `error id` was 454 Family Safety App Locker. I hardly found something online related to a corrupted database: may this be linked to a Microsoft-Family database?

I've been trying to troubleshoot this for a month by now, I already checked if this was a hardware issue, a game issue and so on with some basic troubleshooting: I really think this is a more capillary issue.

Is it wrongly checking if multiple devices are running the same purchase of the game and stops some? (*I read we can play up to 5 simultaneously*).

---

We tried these general system repair cmd commands:

1. `sfc /scannow`
2. `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`

Also I tried to access the AppLocker rules through `secpol.msc`, but apparently there were 0 rules to delete.

I will soon attach the log from Event Viewer and possibly more info as you may request them.

Comment: Are any of the user accounts connected to a Family account?  In other words, are these limited children accounts?  If that is the case, are all these family accounts, linked to the same Microsoft Account?  Instead of submitting a comment you should edit your question.  Please do not submit a comment in response to this comment.

Comment: Added @Ramhound

Comment: Any thoughts? @Ramhound